# How to know a EC2 instance is EC2 Classic or EC2 VPC instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have a list of EC2 instances in my AWS account. So how could I identify whether an instance is a EC2-Classic or is a EC2-VPC type of instance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EC2-VPC instance will have `VPC ID` and `Subnet ID` attributes, the EC2-Classic one will not have it.

If you are using the dashboard, look for `VPC ID` or `Subnet ID` attribute. If using SDK/API, the VPC instances will have `vpc_id` and `subnet_id` attributes defined.

Comment: Thanks for the help HelloV.